# Android, trying to enlarge text if it's on a bigger screen

Tags: android

I am trying to enlarge the size of text in a button as the screen gets wider.  At first it seemed my code worked, but on different android devices it does not work. It will change the font to a big size on a small screen.

This is what I'm doing:

```
 int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        Button but1=new Button(this);
//        but1.setTextColor( Color.parseColor("#ffd79825")); 
        if (w<400)
            but1.setTextSize(10.0f);
        else
        if (w<650)
            but1.setTextSize(14.0f);
        else
             if (w>470)
                but1.setTextSize(18.0f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you making it more complicated, than it is?

Just use dimensions in your values folder:

values:

```
<dimen name="txtSize">10dp</dimen>
```

values-sw400:

```
<dimen name="txtSize">14dp</dimen>
```

And so on.

You can obtain the value like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
float fontSize = res.getDimension(R.dimen.txtSize);
```